# ReferenceError: firebase is not defined in cloud functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase but when I deploy my functions and execute `onWrite()` method this is the error I get:

> ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
>       at exports.sendJobNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event
>   (/user_code/index.js:11:3)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:35:20
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

---

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPaymentNotification = functions.database.ref('payments/{paymentID}').onWrite(event => {
    if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
        return;
      }

      firebase.database().ref('payments').child(event.params.paymentID).once('value').then(function(snap){
            var jobData = snap.val();
            console.log(jobData)
      });
});
```

Comment: Don't you mean to use `admin` instead of `firebase`? e.g. `admin.database().ref()...`

Comment: Thanks. it works with admin

Comment: Thanks this helped me too. But whats weird is that in my Javascript file in my web development i never needed to do that. Its only in the javascript file in cloudFunctions that i have to put admin.database().....

Answer (score 2):

For anyone googling that. You should use "admin" instead of "firebase".

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

in your requires at the start of the function js file, and ensure you use `admin` in place of `firebase` when initializing a connection.

For example:

Use:
`admin.firestore().collection()`

Instead of:
`firebase.firestore().collection()`