# Firebase Function HTTP Trigger - Error: could not handle the request - Firebase Not Defined

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

*Apologies in advance if my syntax isn't correct as I'm a newbie to Firebase (and to node.js).*

Using a HTTP trigger, I'm trying to pull 'awards' data as an object from my Realtime Database. However, based on my setup I am receiving the following error when I execute the URL that I receive from `firebase deploy`.

> Error: could not handle the request

I did change `firebase` to `admin` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954866/referenceerror-firebase-is-not-defined-in-cloud-functions) but that didn't resolve the issue.

Additionally I thought the .catch() method would at least give me an understanding of what the issue is vs just telling me 'error'.

I'm hoping the end result be:

```
{"create_your_own":"false","first_time":"true","five_in_a_row":"true", "share_with_friend": "false"}
```

Any help in deciphering my issue is greatly appreciated.

**Functions log**

[image]

**Realtime Database**

```
fir-db-test-mike
 |
 |__awards
 |   |
 |   |__user01
 |   |   |
 |   |   |__create_your_own: false
 |   |   |__first_time: true
 |   |   |__five_in_a_row: true
 |   |   |__share_with_friend: false
 |   |
 |   |
 |   |__user02
 |       |
 |       |__create_your_own: false
 |       |__first_time: false
 |       |__five_in_a_row: false
 |       |__share_with_friend: false
```

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
require('./src/grabData')(module.exports);
```

**grabData.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

26 module.exports = (event) => {
27   event.grabAwards = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
28     firebase.database().ref('/awards/{pushId}').once('value')
       .then(function(snapshot) {
29       var awards = snapshot.val();
30       res.status(200).send(awards);
31       }).catch(error => {
32       this.errorMessage = 'Error - ' + error.message
33     });
34   })
35 }
```

Comment: You're not importing any module named `firebase`. Instead you import the Firebase Admin SDK as `admin`. So you'll want to use `admin.database()`. Note that is also the [top result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954866/referenceerror-firebase-is-not-defined-in-cloud-functions) when you [search for the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-functions%5D+firebase+is+not+defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not importing any module named `firebase`. Instead you import the Firebase Admin SDK as `admin`. So you'll want to use `admin.database()`.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin') // name used here
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

module.exports = (event) => {
  event.grabAwards = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    admin.database().ref('/awards/{pushId}').once('value') // must match name used here
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        var awards = snapshot.val();
        res.status(200).send(awards);
      }).catch(error => {
        this.errorMessage = 'Error - ' + error.message
      });
  })
}
```